# PHP- Module imagick and Module SourceGuardian error on server

Tags: php, module, imagick

i have developed website where the uesrs redirected by the redirect.php code by taking single parameter. its working fine on my local ubuntu server 18.04 while on the previous web server the site i hosted on. but now i have change the hosting and when the user trying to login to his panel, the system some time redirect on first try but sometime it redirecting the user to the wrong page even if the user provide the correct user id and password:

my code is:

```
ob_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}
      require_once('../classes/MyMethods.php');
      $method = new MyMethods();
      $user_panel = "";$admin_user="";
if(isset($_SESSION['login_params'])){
      $user_panel = $_SESSION['login_params'][0]['grade_flag'];
      $admin_user = $_SESSION['login_params'][0]['admin_user'];
}
if(isset($admin_user) && !empty($admin_user) && $admin_user == 1){
    header("Location: ../grade_admin/index.php");
    }
else{
    switch($user_panel){
        case 1:
            header("Location: ../grade_v/index.php");
        break;
        case 2:
            header("Location: ../grade_viii/index.php");
        break;  
        default:
            header("Location: ".$method->baseUrl());
        break;
        }
 }
 ob_flush();
```

After reading the error_log file on server, it contains the following warnings:

```
[24-Aug-2019 00:51:47 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' 
      already loaded in Unknown on line 0
[24-Aug-2019 00:51:47 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  Module 
     'SourceGuardian' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
```

Where i have never used imagick nor SourceGuardian on my whole web application???

Any Idea???

Comment: go to your php.ini and uncomment ;extension=imagick.so

Comment: VEVonn i don't have access to the php.ini file on my webserver...this problem occurs on web server.

Comment: Well then I assume you are using hosting service with cPanel? Play around with PHP Versions. I am sure changing versions eg. 7.2.1 to 7.2.2 should help you. If not, contact your service provider.